# Constructor functions with properties

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt about javascript constructor function prototipes. So, if I have something like this:

```
a = function (name){this.name = name};
a['b'] = function (age){this.age = age};
c = new a('John');
c.a['b'](30);
```

Is this ok ? And if it is, how **c** object finds **a['b']** function ? Does it go through its **proto** property and reaches constructor function ? Does constructor function sets **b** property on newly created object ?

Comment: The easiest way of determining if syntax is valid is to try it and see if you get syntax errors. In your case, there is not going to be an `a` property on the `c` object. Similarly your other questions are easily answered by trying the code out.

Comment: Have you *tried* it? Because it does *not* locate `a` on `c`.

Comment: @Mike The syntax is fine; it's a *runtime error* happening here…

Comment: `console.log(c);` -> `{ name: 'John' }`

Comment: @smarber And yet: `c.hasOwnProperty()`… `console.log` isn't a conclusive proof of anything.

Comment: @deceze you're right, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this ok ?

No, it fails on the last line with an error. The `c` object doesn't have an `a` property:

```js
a = function (name){this.name = name};
a['b'] = function (age){this.age = age};
c = new a('John');
c.a['b'](30); // TypeError here
```

`new a` creates an object that inherits from the object referenced by `a.prototype`. `a.prototype` doesn't have an `a` property.

If you wanted to get to `a` from `c`, `a.prototype` does have a `constructor` property that refers to `a`, and `c` in inherits that property, so:

```
c.constructor['b'](30);
```

**but**, doing that would call the second function with `this` referring to `c.constructor`, and thus add an `age` property to the first function:

```js
a = function (name){this.name = name};
a['b'] = function (age){this.age = age};
c = new a('John');
c.constructor['b'](30);
console.log(a.age); // 30
```

Stepping back, the overall structure of

```
a = function (name){this.name = name};
a['b'] = function (age){this.age = age};
c = new a('John');
```

...doesn't make much sense. There's usually no reason to put `b` on `a` like that.

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*: Declare your variables.

Comment: So, _new_ keyword creates a new object, sets its __proto__ property to constructors prototype and then executes constructor function with _this_ as newly created object ? Where are constructors property (function _a['b']_ in this case) in all that ? I took some javascript course where we created our own "jQuery", and there I run on these things.. And I'm sorry if my questions aren't clear enough, because I don't have much experience in javascript.

Comment: @Danilo: *" Where are constructors property (function a['b'] in this case) in all that ?"* On the constructor. They're not involved in the new object at all (other than indirectly through the `constructor` property).

Comment: @Crowder Ok, thanks for the answers..